# ruby unicorn fork process A, and how to A send it's output to nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fork, unicorn

here is my code, AppLogger.error output msg to stdout. first, i call fork to produce a process pid, in the process, @app.call(env) is a long time task and will output a result. after fork, i call detach to avoid a zombie.

```
    pid = fork{
        AppLogger.error "fork"
        @app.call(env)
        AppLogger.error "end fork"
    }
    Process.detach(pid)
```

but web browser get a 500. so what should i do to send result to nginx.

Comment: and i don't want current unicorn process output result to nginx, just want fork process output result to nginx

Comment: What's the purpose of forking? Clearly you intend to wait for the result. So just do it in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`fork` with a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-fork) the code within the block is going to run in a child process. Therefore your server is *likely* waiting for the output of the parent process, doesn't receive a response and 500s (if you can post the details of the 500 that would help!)

To pass the output of the child process back to the parent process you can use a [pipe](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-pipe):

```
reader, writer = IO.pipe

pid = fork {
    reader.close

    AppLogger.error "fork"
    writer.write(@app.call(env))
    AppLogger.error "end fork"
}

writer.close
Process.wait(pid)

response_to_client = reader.read
```

As mentioned by Sergio, this doesn't make a ton of sense, especially in the context of Unicorn, since Unicorn is already forking off child processes to execute your web requests.

Comment: firstly, thk for your answer. but i don't want parent process to wait for child process. what I want to is child process to output result to nginx, and parent process(unicorn process) continue to accept nginx's request.

Comment: @zql this is what unicorn does already: https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb#L432 there's no need for you to perform additional forks. If you're looking to scale up unicorn just increase the number of `worker_processes`: http://unicorn.bogomips.org/TUNING.html